# Alternate construction of Cartesian product of two sets

Tags: set-theory

Halmos constructs the Cartesian product of two sets $A$and $B$ through the axiom of specification by applying the condition "$x = (a, b) \text{ for some } a\in A\text{ and for some } b\in B$" to the power set of the power set of the union of $A$ and $B$, which he denotes as $\mathcal{P(P(} A\cup B))$. (So he is in fact using axioms of unions and power sets too.)

But I thought of a different construction like this. Given two sets $A$ and $B$, for every $a\in A$ and for every $b\in B$, there exists the ordered pair $(a,b)$ (which Halmos defined to be $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$) by repeated application of axiom of pairs. Now can I say that we can form a set of all such ordered pairs?

Comment: From the Axiom of Pairing it follows that $(a,b)$ is a set for each $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, but you need more (e.g. power set and union, as in Halmos' construction) to show that the class of all such pairs forms a set.

Comment: @Vsotvep Thanks! That answers it.

Comment: @Vsotvep You should make that an answer.

Comment: @NoahSchweber done

Answer (score 1):

You really do need stronger assumptions than only the Axiom of Pairing. The Axiom shows that $(a,b)$ is a set for each $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, but you have no way of collecting all these ordered pairs in a set.

This can be done with the Axiom of Power Set and the Axiom of Union, as in Halmos' book.

Alternatively it can be done with the Axiom of Replacement / Collection (see for example [the construction of products in Kripke-Platek Set Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke%E2%80%93Platek_set_theory#Proof_that_Cartesian_products_exist)).